# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value 'xxx' at path "_id"

Tags: arrays, json, mongoose

I have an array in request as:

```
{
"acceptedBookings": [
    {
        "id": "e1f66d7a852986709f665c3",
        "Date": "2020-02-04T05:03:25.332Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to update the "date" for every "id". However If I search as

`await Booking.findById( acceptedBookings[0].id )` or

`await Booking.findOne({_id : acceptedBookings[0].id})`

It does not give a response

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing  wrong member, what you want is:
let's assume your `map` is something like

```
  const acceptedBookings = {
  "accepted": [{
          "id": "e1f66d7a852986709f665c3",
          "Date": "2020-02-04T05:03:25.332Z"
      },
      {
          "id": "i123",
          "Date": "2020-02-04T05:03:25.332Z"
      },
      {
          "id": "i123",
          "Date": "2020-02-04T05:03:25.332Z"
      }
  ]
};

console.log(acceptedBookings.accepted[0].id); // e1f66d7a852986709f665c3
console.log(acceptedBookings.accepted[1].id); // i123

await Booking.findById( acceptedBookings.accepted[0].id ) //should work fine
```

Remember the object you've created that is not an `array` it's `map/object` with a `key: value` pair
thus get the right array/element first then access it's members

Comment: update your question with the codes of ```Booking.findOne()``` method